# selected items from the ListBoxes are the filter .criteria1 in the table

Tags: vba, filter, listbox, criteria, listobject

In active workbook.Sheets(1) I have a ListBoxes("List Box 1").
First I select items form this ListBoxes, then I want filtered table("table 1") in second worksheet.
I don’t know why it doesn’t work.

'''

```
Sub group()

Dim i, j As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wbNew As Workbook
Dim ListaI As Object 'listbox
Dim Wynik As String

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

lastrow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(wb.Sheets(3).Columns("A:A")) 'in this column is a list of items


Set ListaI = wb.Sheets(1).ListBoxes("List Box 1") ' this listbox include value from wb.Sheets(3).Columns("A:A")

For i = 2 To lastrow
If ListaI.Selected(i) Then
    j = j + 1
    If j > 1 Then Wynik = Wynik ' to omit empty
    Wynik = Wynik & Chr(34) & ListaI.List(i) & Chr(34) & ", "
    
    
 End If
 Next


Wynik = Left(Wynik, Len(Wynik) - 2) ' to delite last comma, for example: "pen", "window", "door"


Set wbNew = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\username\Desktop\nameofphile.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)

With wbNew.Sheets("name")
    .ListObjects("table 1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Wynik, _
     Operator:=xlFilterValues ' assigning selected values to a filter in a table
    
End With




End Sub
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Name your variables to something meaningful (i is hard to understand, counter it's easier)
- Indent your code properly (you can use [Rubberduckvba.com](http://Rubberduckvba.com)) to help you with data
- Try to break your code into pieces (e.g. first set references, then counter, then create the filter array, then apply it)
- Comment your code

---

Read code's comments and adjust it to fit your needs

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FilterTableBySelectedItem()
    
    ' Set a referece to the workbook holding the listbox
    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Set sourceWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
    
    ' Set a reference to the worksheet holding the listbox
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheet = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Set a reference to the listbox
    Dim sourceListbox As ListBox
    Set sourceListbox = sourceSheet.ListBoxes("List Box 1")
    
    ' Get total selected items in listbox
    Dim counter As Long
    For counter = 1 To sourceListbox.ListCount
        If sourceListbox.Selected(counter) Then
            Dim totalSelected As Long
            totalSelected = totalSelected + 1
        End If
    Next counter
    
    ' Add the selected items to an array
    Dim selectedItems As Variant
    ReDim selectedItems(totalSelected - 1)
    For counter = 1 To sourceListbox.ListCount
        If sourceListbox.Selected(counter) Then
            Dim selectedCounter As Long
            selectedItems(selectedCounter) = sourceListbox.List(counter)
            selectedCounter = selectedCounter + 1
        End If
    Next counter
    
    ' Uncomment this next lines if you plan to use the filter in another way,
    'Dim selectedItemsFilter As String
    'selectedItemsFilter = Join(selectedItems, ",")
    
    ' Set a reference to the workbook holding the table
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Temp\test.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)
    
    ' Set a reference to the worksheet holding the table
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Set a reference to the table
    Dim targetTable As ListObject
    Set targetTable = targetSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
    
    ' Filter the table using the array of selected items
    targetTable.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=selectedItems, Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much. I had an amazing problem with adding the selected items from listbox to an array. Works really fine :)